# -D for visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

I have to compile one executable on Windows, the first time.  I'm using visual studio 2003 and want the equivalent of a command line macro definition.

What's the VS equivalent of `g++ -Dthismacro=1`?

**Update**
For VS 2003, I found it this way.  Right clicking on the project, I go to "Properties".  From there, it's Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions

Comment: The title is a little misleading. I thought for a minute that you were giving VS a grade of D minus. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since you seem to be coming from a linux-flavor, why not use the commandline: the argument for macro definition is actually the same, except the compiler executable is cl and not g++:

> cl -Dthismacro=1

although the documentation says the convention is to use /D, most (all?) arguments can be used with the - switch.

When using visual Studio, you can verify this: if you add a preprocessor symbol the way earlz suggested, this can be seen as /D"thismacro=1" option under Configuration->C/C++->Command Line

Answer (score 2):

If you right click on the project, it should bring up a project configuration page. Goto "build" and then you should be able to define preprocessor symbols.. (hopefully it works the same in 2003 as 2008)